# Constructing Regular Expressions in Java

Tags: java, regex

I've gone through a couple of tutorials online on Java regular expressions, but I'm still finding it pretty difficult to construct regular expressions.

Sample Text (A tweet):

```
@HIMYM_CBS: Barney Stinson. That Guy's Awesome
```

Another Sample:

```
Barney Stinson.  @HIMYM_CBS: That Guy's Awesome
```

This is a tweet to HIMYM_CBS.

What I want to accomplish is, given any tweet, I want to know if that tweet is addressed to anyone (like in this case HIMYM_CBS). It doesn't matter whom it's addressed to.

My Question is: So what should be my line of thought for constructing a regular expression to accomplish this?

The tweets are stored as a String:

```
String Tweet = "@HIMYM_CBS: Barney Stinson. That Guy's Awesome";
```

Comment: What problem are you having?

Comment: @RohitJain, I need help creating a regular expression for this case

Comment: It depends on what a legal name of a tweeter can be. Twitter documentation can probably tell you that.

Comment: Thanks all for the helpful answers but Unfortunately I can only accept one :(

Comment: Could someone please explain why this is off topic? I know that my effort to solve my problem is not demonstrated, but that is because regular expressions are confusing to me and I was not able to logically come up with correct regex even though I have gone some through tutorials online. Rather than asking for a regex which solves my problem, I was asking for the logic or the "line of thought" for constructing regular expressions, which would help me construct my own in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String tweet = "@HIMYM_CBS: Barney Stinson. That Guy's Awesome";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("@(\\w+)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(tweet);
if (m.find()) {
  System.out.println(m.group(1));
} else {
  System.out.println("not found.");
}
```

Perhaps you want to check api documentation of [Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) class.

In the code `\w` means a word character which is equivalent to `[a-zA-Z_0-9]`.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not able to understand \\w*. \w is a word character? What does the first \ in \\w= do?

Comment: This will give you all the characters after @. This is also an another way.

Comment: @Chaos: The regular expression is `@(\w+)`. But in Java, regular expressions are made from Strings and in Strings, the `\ ` character is special, so to include a `\ ` in a String, we `escape` it with another `\ `. Hence: `"@(\\w+)"`

Comment: Won't  System.out.println(m.group(1)); return the whole string if there is no match? In that case will it go to the else statement at all?

Comment: @Chaos `m.find()` will return `false` when there's no match. Therefore, the flow goes to `else` branch.

Comment: @Chaos If there's no match, m.group(1) will throw an exception.

Answer (score 4):

Twitter usernames are a maximum of 15 characters long, and begin with a @, and can only contain letters numbers and underscores.

So the regular expression you want to use is:

```
(?<=\s|\A)@(\w{1,15})
^   ^ ^^ ^^^^ ^     ^ ")" ends a matching group.
|   | || |||| | matches preceding expression between 1 and 15 times.
|   | || |||| "\w" matches [a-zA-Z0-9_]
|   | || ||| "(" begins a matching group
|   | || || literal "@"
|   | || | ")" ends the zero-width lookbehind assertion
|   | || "\A" will match the beginning of the string
|   | | "|" denotes that either this or that matches
|   | "\s" matches a space character
| "(?<=" is the beginning of a zero-width lookbehind assertion
```

Comment: Sorry, using \b is wrong here.  I never use it next to non-word characters such as @; I think it matches only between a word character and a non-word character (or at the beginning or end of the source), so the above will match `abc@def` but not `abc @def` and not the "Another Sample" in the original question.

Comment: @ajb, Ah!  You are correct, I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Would the regular expression

```
@\\w+
```

work?

Comment: would this work if there are something before @ too?

Comment: @Chaos Yes, I believe it would...

Comment: Why don't you use `@\\w+` instead or is it not available in the java flavor ?

Comment: @HamZa I certainly could use \w. I'll edit.

Answer (score 1):

```
/(?:^|(?<=\s))@([A-Za-z_0-9]+)(?=[.?,:]?\s)/
```

> You can only use letters, numbers or the underscore symbol (_) in a Twitter handle.

***Sample test case** :*
`@This` (matched at the start of a line) regex *ignores@this* but matches on `@separate` tokens as well as tokens at the end of a sentence like `@this`. or `@this`? (without picking the `.` or the `?`) and `@this`: and `@this`, as in a direct message SO style. And yes any *email@address.com* in the tweets is ignored too.

The regex while matching on `@` also lets you quickly access what's after it (like `userid` in `@userid`) by picking it up form the `Matcher#group(1)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Test {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String Tweet = "@HIMYM_CBS: Barney Stinson. That Guy's Awesome";
        String regex = "@([^:]+)";
        Pattern compile = Pattern.compile(regex);
        Matcher matcher = compile.matcher(Tweet);
        if (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
        }

    }

}
```

Output :`HIMYM_CBS`

Comment: what does [^:] mean? not colon?

Comment: This means that get all the string between @ and : . Your username/id is between @ and :. This will fetch the value.

Comment: @Chaos yes, it means "anything other than a :". Makky's regex will find the beginning @, then match up to the next :.

Comment: This would be a more useful answer if you explained *why* it worked, rather than just providing a solution.

Comment: ok thanks. I will try to be more informative next time.